# Why does my Unity C# List not load from FromJSON()?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using Unity and trying to load in data from JSON files. It finds the files, but no data comes through. when I do a Debug.Log(count) on it it tells me there are zero entries. But the same code for planets works fine. (I haven't got any code in the agent's field yet).

I even used a wrapper like you're supposed to. Here are the object and its wrapper:

```
    public class StructureList
    {
        public List<Structure> structures = new List<Structure>();
    }

    public class Structure
    {

        public int id;
        public string structureName;
        public int productionMaterials; 
        public int productionPersonnel;
        public int defensiveShields;
        public int offensiveDamage;
        public int defensiveIonDamage;
        public int constructionShip;
        public int constructionStructure;
        public int constructionArmy;
        public int detectionFleet;
        public int detectionAgents;
        public string structureDescription;
        public int colonyId;
        public int costCrew;
        public int costMaterials;
    }
```

here's the json file:

```
{
  "structures": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "structureName": "Factory",
      "productionMaterials": 5,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "A basic factory that provides construction materials to the empire.",
      "costCrew": 100,
      "costMaterials": 200,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "structureName": "Recruitment Center",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 5,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "A basic structure that recruits personnel for employ in the empire.",
      "costCrew": 200,
      "costMaterials": 100,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "structureName": "Shield Generator",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 10,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "A planetary shield generator that will defend against orbital bombardment. Can defend against incursions if their are multiple.",
      "costCrew": 25,
      "costMaterials": 200,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "structureName": "SOL Platform",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 10,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "A Surface to Orbit laser turret that fires at ships which come close enough for orbital bombardments.",
      "costCrew": 25,
      "costMaterials": 350,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "structureName": "Ion Cannon",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 5,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "A low orbit station designed to build space worthy ships.",
      "costCrew": 25,
      "costMaterials": 250,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "structureName": "Shipyard",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 10,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "A base of operations with construction crews for building other structures.",
      "costCrew": 500,
      "costMaterials": 250,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "structureName": "Construction Yard",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 10,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "A training center that turns personnel into armies. Also, helps detect enemy agents.",
      "costCrew": 500,
      "costMaterials": 500,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "structureName": "Barracks",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 5,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 5,
      "structureDescription": "An empty planet, devoid of life.",
      "costCrew": 250,
      "costMaterials": 500,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "structureName": "Sensor Array",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 10,
      "detectionAgents": 0,
      "structureDescription": "Detects fleets at a distance, incoming to the planet.",
      "costCrew": 10,
      "costMaterials": 500,
      "colonyId": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "structureName": "Communications Array",
      "productionMaterials": 0,
      "productionPersonnel": 0,
      "defensiveShields": 0,
      "offensiveDamage": 0,
      "defensiveIonDamage": 0,
      "constructionShip": 0,
      "constructionStructure": 0,
      "constructionArmy": 0,
      "detectionFleet": 0,
      "detectionAgents": 10,
      "structureDescription": "Used to decrypt messages being sent out from the planet, in order to detect enemy agents.",
      "costCrew": 150,
      "costMaterials": 50,
      "colonyId": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's my loading code:

````
        public static PlanetList planets;
        public static StructureList structures;
        public static AgentList agents;

        public static void LoadData()
        {
            string planetPath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/PlanetDB.json";
            string structurePath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/StructureDB.json";
            string agentPath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/AgentDB.json";

            if (File.Exists(planetPath))
            {
                string planetsdataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(planetPath);
                planets = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlanetList>(planetsdataAsJson);
                Debug.Log("Planets Loaded: " + planets.planets.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                planets = new PlanetList();
                Debug.LogError("FAILED TO LOAD PLANETDATA");
            }

            if (File.Exists(structurePath))
            {
                string structuresdataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(structurePath);
                structures = JsonUtility.FromJson<StructureList>(structuresdataAsJson);
                Debug.Log("Structures Loaded: " + structures.structures.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                structures = new StructureList();
                Debug.LogError("FAILED TO LOAD STRUCUREDATA");
            }

            if (File.Exists(agentPath))
            {
                string agentsdataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(agentPath);
                agents = JsonUtility.FromJson<AgentList>(agentsdataAsJson);
                Debug.Log("Agents Loaded: " + agents.agents.Count);
            }
            else
            {
                agents = new AgentList();
                Debug.LogError("FAILED TO LOAD AGENTDATA");
            }
        }
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `[Serializable]` attribute :)

From https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html:

> It must be a plain class/struct marked with the Serializable attribute.

Add the attributes and it will deserialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class StructureList
{
    public List<Structure> structures = new List<Structure>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Structure
{
    public int id;
    public string structureName;
    public int productionMaterials;
    public int productionPersonnel;
    public int defensiveShields;
    public int offensiveDamage;
    public int defensiveIonDamage;
    public int constructionShip;
    public int constructionStructure;
    public int constructionArmy;
    public int detectionFleet;
    public int detectionAgents;
    public string structureDescription;
    public int colonyId;
    public int costCrew;
    public int costMaterials;
}
```